# Setting CustomErrors to On in Web.Config crashes site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, configuration, web-config, custom-errors

I have an ASP.NET MVC3 site where CustomErrors are set to Off in Web.config. Naturally, I want to set it to on. However, when setting it to on:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error.aspx" />
```

accessing the site gives the error-page promptly.

Having it to Off doesn't give an error, and the site functions perfectly. Is there a silent error, that customErrors catches, but I don't see? Does it have something to do with me using session-variables?

This happens when deployed to IIS, but not in my dev-environment.

Comment: is the Error.aspx in the root?

Comment: Take a look at the EventLog of your server. It might contain additional information about the error.

Comment: Does referring to a .html page works, instead of .aspx?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Investigating :)

Comment: Cheers! I didn't have the correct Error.aspx in place, even though I thought so. I was led to it by the machine's EventLog.